# How to start Tanuki Software Wrapper automatically on interval of 2 hours

Tags: java, batch-file

I am using Tanuki Software Wrapper for building a java application as Windows Service . I follow the example [Simple HelloWorldServer Java Class](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/qna-service.html#helloworld) and it works fine . I have made configure in wrapper.conf file `wrapper.ntservice.starttype = AUTO_START` for automatically starting the service on windows system starting .

But i want that my service would be automatically started on every two hours , how can i do it , if any one has idea please help me .

Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: How about using the [windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have done through following configuration in the wrapper.conf file as

```
wrapper.pausable=TRUE
wrapper.pause-on-startup=TRUE
wrapper.timer.1.interval=minute=120
wrapper.timer.1.action=restart, resume
wrapper.on_exit.default=PAUSE
```

It basically pause the wrapper action after main jvm(java application) is closed , and then after 2 hours it automatically restart wrapper's local JVM and resume the required output with updated data .

Thanks to all for trying to help me .

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep your java application running, and schedule tasks from within your application.

E.g. use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

If you schedule a task in your main() method, a new Timer Thread is started, so the application will keep running after the main() has ended, and keep executing the scheduled task at the rate you specified.

Comment: Actually i have already done it but i want to do through windows service because i want my another thread run even Java JVM is dead .

Answer (score 0):

Ajeet,
As GreyFairer said, it is usually a good idea to run tasks from within the JVM, especially if they happen often.

The Wrapper's ability to stop and start the JVM using the pausable feature definitely works as well.  This approach can be better if your JVM is large, and the task it needs to complete is relatively infrequent.  There is a bit of load to launch a JVM.

Relaunching the JVM as you are doing also has the benefit of allowing you to change the configuration for each invocation if you combine configuration include files with the wrapper.restart.reload_configuration=TRUE property.  You can modify the include file as needed so each JVM runs with the needed information.  (There are of course ways of getting the same results within a single JVM invocation if needed.)

Cheers, Leif